# Lombok not working in springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, lombok

I want to bean or inject logger so that I don't end up creating an object of logger in each and every class.

So I am trying to integrate Lombok which would help me to resolve lot of things including logger.

Here is my code:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;    
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
    
@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {
   
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyApplication.class);
    
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
        log.debug("Hello");
        logger.info("Info log", MyApplication.class.getSimpleName());
  }
}
```

But this is giving me error when I try to use log directly

IDE error -

> log cannot be resolved

Console runtime error -

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot
> invoke "org.slf4j.Logger.info(String, Object)" because
> "com.MyApplication .log" is null  at
> com.MyApplication.main(MyApplication .java:27)

**Pom.xml**

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
  <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
  <version>1.18.12</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.5</version>
</dependency>
```

I have also installed lomback to my Eclipse IDE

Comment: for some ideas it's also necessary to add the lombok plugin before it works. did you do that?

Comment: Are you running the application from within the IDE? If so, which IDE do you use?

Comment: @MarkBramnik I am using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (includes Incubating components)

Version: 2021-03 (4.19.0)

Comment: @Stultuske I have already added lomback to my Eclipse IDE as software

Comment: Ok, Like here: see https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-ide#eclipse for example? And another question: When you run the app outside the ide (like `java -jar myapp.jar`) do you also see the error? I think you can eliminate the eclipse related issues with this check...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you didn't install the Lombok plugin in your IDE.

Take a look at https://projectlombok.org/setup/overview under IDEs. There you can find instructions on how to install the plugin on most common used IDEs.

Also try to remove the logger from your code. This line:

```java
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyApplication.class);
```

Because this is what lombok is adding at compile time. And you don't need the `logging` dependency because it's already part of spring-boot

Comment: I have already installed lomback with Eclipse let me update my question

Comment: Thanks, but after removing the line it is still not working for me, is something wrong with my pom.xml file?

Comment: Maybe you can try to create a new project using start.spring.io. Make sure that you add lombok and just add the @Slf4j annotation and a log.info statement. If that doesn't work then I would assume that your IDE plugin is broken.

Comment: I tried creating a new project and followed the steps that you mentioned and not working in that too. So it might be possible that IDE plugin is broken. Or may be I was googling more and lomback might not be compatible with latest java version

Comment: You are right, @PeterLustig